# livelossplot keras plot per epoch

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

> I'm trying to plot a cost function and accurancy function in Keras.
> However, when I want to play with my times of epoch, for instance 100 times, I will get 100 >plots
> in phyton, which I have to delete the n epoch plot before the  n + 1 epoch plot will be presented.
> I would like to have one figure where I can see all the 100 epoch times once.
> my code:

```
import pandas as pd
forecast_demo = pd.read_csv('forcastdemo.csv')
forecast_demo.head()

X_train = forecast_demo[['index', 'quarter']]
y_train = forecast_demo.revenue
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras import models

from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, BatchNormalization
from IPython.core.display import Image

inputs = Input(shape=(2,))              
x = BatchNormalization()(inputs)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = Dense(1)(x)      


model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
keras.utils.plot_model(model,to_file='images/oefening2.png', show_shapes=True)
Image('images/oefening2.png')

model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error, # of keras.losses.mean_absolute_percentage_error, keras.losses.mean_absolute_error (voor regressie)
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=keras.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error # of keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error, keras.metrics.mean_squared_error
)


from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras

## here I'll get 100 plots. 
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=20, 
                    epochs=100,  
                    callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras()],
                    verbose=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives the same result what you are expecting (one figure with 100  epoch times plotted). 
I ran the above code with [abalone dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#in_memory_data) in `Google colab` using `Tensorflow version==2.7`.

Please check here:

```
from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras
 
history = model.fit(abalone_features, abalone_labels,
                    batch_size=20, 
                    epochs=100,
                    verbose=2,
                    callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras()])
                    #verbose=False)
```

Output:[image]

```
Loss
    loss                 (min:    4.342, max:   16.475, cur:    4.358)
mean_absolute_percentage_error
    mean_absolute_percentage_error   (min:   15.522, max:   29.032, cur:   15.898)
166/166 - 1s - loss: 4.3578 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 15.8985 - 694ms/epoch - 4ms/step
```

Please specify the `TensorFlow version` and `environment details` where you are getting this issue.